# Invariant subspace concept - generalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Suppose $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ are linear maps. Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be such a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that $A(X)=B(X)$. Where can I read more about such subspaces $X$? Is there a common name for them? I am interested in some sort of a general theory.

**Motivation:**

If $n=m$ and $B=\operatorname{Id}$ then $X$ is called an *A-invariant subspace* of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, if $\operatorname{dim}(X)=1$ then $X$ is simply spanned by some eigenvector of $A$.

This makes me think of eigenvectors of some matrix as of its "similarity" to the identity matrix, because if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $X=\operatorname{Span}(x)$ then $A(X)=\operatorname{Id}(X)$. But what if I want to capture the similarity between matrix $A$ and some nonidentity matrix $B$? And what if they are not square? This leads me to the question above.

Comment: Take a basis for $X$, say $\beta$. $A(X) = B(X)$ indicates that the span of $\beta$ via A is equivalent to the span of $\beta$ via B. That is, the span of $A(\beta)$ is equivalent to the span of $B(\beta)$.

Comment: When $X$ is one-dimensional, this is a well studied problem (barring some restrictions on $A$ and $B$) that comes up in mechanics. It is sometimes called a "generalized eigenvector" problem. See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) for example, under "additional topics", where it's called a generalized eigenvalue problem (in the second sense). Not a full generalization if what you wanted, but it might give you a place to start looking for additional references.

Comment: @EuYu, thank you very much! It seems to be a good place to start.